# Unexplainable space under div

Tags: html, css

I have three div's next to eachother, but when the content of one or more of the div's gets too big, it causes extra space underneath the div. This causes the div's not to be aligned vertically. I have no idea how to stop this from happening.

HTML:

```
<div id="recents">
<div id="upload" class="box">
    <img class="cover" onclick="changeHash2(&quot;track=1328030460&amp;prev=user=CupOfTea696&quot;);" src="http://ttrcustoms.us/track_images/uploads/1328030460-Cover.jpg">
    <span>Miss May I<br>
    Monument (Guitar) v1 and xtra te<br>
    Track</span>
    <span class="tmp"><a href="download.php?uri1328030460" target="_blank"><img src="http://ttrcustoms.us/iCons/download.png"></a> <img onclick="changeHash2(&quot;track=1328030460&amp;prev=user=CupOfTea696&quot;);" src="http://ttrcustoms.us/iCons/info.png"> <img onclick="trackpopup(&quot;1328030460&quot;);" src="http://ttrcustoms.us/iCons/rate.png"></span>
</div>
<div id="spacer"></div>
<div id="upload" class="box">
    <img class="cover" onclick="changeHash2(&quot;track=1327679448&amp;prev=user=CupOfTea696&quot;);" src="http://ttrcustoms.us/track_images/uploads/1327679448-Cover.jpg">
    <span>Miss May I<br>
    Monument Coop and xtra te<br>
    Track</span>
    <span class="tmp"><a href="download.php?uri1327679448" target="_blank"><img src="http://ttrcustoms.us/iCons/download.png"></a> <img onclick="changeHash2(&quot;track=1327679448&amp;prev=user=CupOfTea696&quot;);" src="http://ttrcustoms.us/iCons/info.png"> <img onclick="trackpopup(&quot;1327679448&quot;);" src="http://ttrcustoms.us/iCons/rate.png"></span>
</div>
<div id="spacer"></div>
<div id="upload" class="box">
    <img class="cover" onclick="changeHash2(&quot;track=1308426773&amp;prev=user=CupOfTea696&quot;);" src="http://ttrcustoms.us/track_images/uploads/1330860552-EmbraceTheGutter.jpg">
    <span>The Autumn Offering<br>
    Embrace The Gutter and xtra te<br>
    Track</span>
    <span class="tmp"><a href="download.php?uri1308426773" target="_blank"><img src="http://ttrcustoms.us/iCons/download.png"></a> <img onclick="changeHash2(&quot;track=1308426773&amp;prev=user=CupOfTea696&quot;);" src="http://ttrcustoms.us/iCons/info.png"> <img onclick="trackpopup(&quot;1308426773&quot;);" src="http://ttrcustoms.us/iCons/rate.png"></span>
</div>
```

​​​​​​​​​​

CSS:

```
.box{
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0 2em 2em 2em ;
    border: 1px solid #FA0;
    color: #FFF;
    -moz-border-radius: 13px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 13px;
    border-radius: 13px;
    background-color: #222;
    font: 0.9em Calibri, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

a:link, a:visited{
    color: #C6CDE0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
#recents{
    position: relative;
}
#upload{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #404040;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 7px;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 0px;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.25s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.25s;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.25s;
    transition: background-color 0.25s;
}
#upload:hover{
    background-color: #303030;
}
#upload span.tmp{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 7px;
    right: 7px;

}
#upload .cover{
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 3px;
    moz-border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
#upload img{
    cursor: pointer;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.25s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.25s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.25s;
    transition: opacity 0.25s;
}
#upload img:hover{
    opacity: 0.5;
}
#spacer{
    width: 1%;
    height: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
}​
```

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/QvGdA/

Comment: Have you tried `#upload{vertical-align:top;}`? Note that an id should be an **unique** identifier. Use `class = "upload box"` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you watch carefully, you can see that every boxes' last `Track` words are aligned in one line, they (generally the last line of the given box) form the `baseline` of an `inline-block`. Demonstration with a "ruler" div added: http://jsfiddle.net/QvGdA/2/

Add `vertical-align: top;` to `#upload`, and it's fixed, see http://jsfiddle.net/QvGdA/1/